# Wicket CheckBox change visibility of other component

Tags: java, checkbox, datepicker, wicket

I have a Wicket 7 CheckBox and a hidden DateTextField. 
When I click on a CheckBox  I want the DateTextField to be appeared and vice versa.
For this reason I have added the DateTextField in a WebMarkUpContainer. 
If possible I dont want to use Ajax.
The problem is that the WebMarkUpContainer is always hidden.
In general my code is as follows:

```
class ResultsPanel extends Panel{

private static final class ResultsPage {

final DateTextField startDate = new DateTextField("startDate",  new DateTextFieldConfig().withLanguage("el");

final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("checkBox");

final WebMarkupContainer wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("wmc");

   // bla bla bla

public Results(String id, CompoundPropertyModel propertyModel) {

            super(id, propertyModel);            
            add(checkBox);  
            wmc.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);                     
            wmc.add(startDate);
            add(wmc.setVisible(false));  
            }

public ResultsPanel(String id){
  super(id);   
  add(new ResultsPage("resultsPage", new CompoundPropertyModel()));
}

}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use Ajax? This would be incredibly easy with a simple AjaxCheckBox and overriding the onUpdate method.

Comment: Obviously.. but I want to find out which method of CheckBox I have to override in order to make it work without Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't need to trigger any server side code when you click on the checkbox, you can consider to use some simple JavaScript code to hide/show the DateTextField. This code can be attached to the checkbox using a JavaScriptHeaderItem.  You can find more details in the user guide.

**update**

In Wicket 7.x You can try

```
    new CheckBox("id", model) { 
    protected boolean wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications() {
     return true;
 } 
    protected void onSelectionChanged(Boolean newSelection) {
     // do something, page will be rerendered; 
} };
```

Comment: I want to make it work with simple Java Wicket code.. I have tried the overriden method onChange(){ .. } in the CheckBox but it doesnt seem to work..

Comment: Than you should override wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications() to force server roundtrips on each selection change:

    // Wicket 7.x
    new CheckBox("id", model) {
        protected boolean wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications() {
            return true;
            }
 
        protected void onSelectionChanged(Boolean newSelection) {
            // do something, page will be rerendered;
        }
    };